# Why does Java Garbage Collection perform in batch?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I understand that Garbage Collection in Java runs automatically by freeing up spaces used up by objects that are not reachable any more.

But why does it do that in a batch mode? References to heap objects are already stored in a stack so why not free those objects as and when the frame containing those references is popped out from the stack?

Comment: Say you create an object which escapes the current method. When would this object be cleaned up?

Comment: Note: objects which don't escape a method c an be placed on the stack using "Escape Analysis" so the objects placed on the heap are ones it can't work out whether they live after the method returns.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Wasn't aware of the Escape Analysis concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, generally speaking the fact that one of the references to the object (which was used in a method) is destroyed is not sufficient to state that the object is not reachable any more via any other path (for example method could share the reference by assigning it to a field of any object hence making the created object referenced from the heap as well). Just consider the following example :

```
    public class GarbageCollectionReferenceShareDemo {
    
        private Object objectReference;
    
        public void runDemo() {
            final Object methodReference = new Object();
            objectReference = methodReference;
        }
    }
```

In the example above the reference to the object being created is also published into a field of a class. After the execution of the `runDemo` method is complete the `methodReference` reference variable will be destroyed (when popping the stack frame). However, it is essential to realize that only the **reference** will be destroyed and not the created object (which is stored in the heap). The JVM runtime can not clean up the created object since it has to analyze whether it is reachable or not and judging from the example above doing it requires scanning references out of the method as well.

So long story short : in order to determine whether the object is reachable or not garbage collector has to scan all paths starting from the GC roots, which mainly include all thread's stacks and global variables , eg static fields. Only this approach allows to cope with the cases when a reference is shared out of the method via an assignment.

However, the garbage collection topic is quite an extensive one, hence if you are interested in the details of Garbage Collection then I would strongly recommend following book which will spread a light on quite a lot of GC details :

[The Garbage Collection Handbook: The Art of Automatic Memory Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420082795)